# Function/s equivalent to "bwareaopen" and "bwconhull" supported for C / C++ code generation (MATLAB)

Tags: image-processing, matlab-coder

This is with reference to a code suggested by [Image Analyst given here](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195933-function-imfindcircles-detects-false-circles). I am trying to generate C code for the algorithm. According to the document ["Functions and Objects Supported for C and C++ Code Generation"](http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html), MATLAB functions bwconhull and bwareaopen aren't readily supported for C / C++ code generation. What are the alternative functions I can use?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, "bwconnhull" and "bwareaopen" aren't directly supported, but there are a number of foundational morphological functions that are available. Unfortunately, it's a bit of work to recreate those two routines using the smaller subset of functions (such as bwperim, bwselect, bwtraceboundary, and bwmorph). I believe it is actually possible, but the implementation will depend a bit on how exactly the routines are being used in your code.

A good guide to morphological operations and their relationship to each other is given in Gonzales and Woods ([http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Image-Processing-3rd-Edition/dp/013168728X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013168728X)).  In my old copy, it's in Chapter 8 under Morphology, but I think it's in Chapter 9 in newer editions.

Sadly, I know of no drop-in replacement, and you'll end up writing new ones and testing them in your application.  On the plus side, morphological operations are very well explained and defined, and they relate to each other in an elegant way, so you should have all the tools you need in those other functions.

Comment: Yeah, I have read this book and I agree it's possible. Considering the deadline of my projects that I've gotta stick to, writing the entire algorithm using fundamental morphological functions doesn't seem feasible. Sigh. I initially didn't know that Mathworks supported only a subset of MATLAB functions for code generation!